# how to show delete button in top right corner of Image?

Tags: jquery, html

i would like to show delete button at top right corner to image?
how could i achieve this?

my html is like this :-

main image :

```
<img id="' + id + '" src="../Images/DefaultPhotoMale.png" class="' + item + '" width="40" height="40" alt="image" title="' + projectTitle + '" style="cursor:pointer" />
```

x button image to display in top-right of above image

- `'<img id="' + item.Soid + '" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico" style="display:none" title="Remove Specialization" />`

No background image set please, i need click event for that delete button
something like this :

[image]

Comment: make the large image to the background of a div with relative layout and then put the X button in that same div with position absolute top: 0px; right: 0px;

Comment: i cannot, those images are loading dynamically, it's jquery carousellist item

Comment: Actually, letter `'×'` will do just fine. )

Comment: You'll need to wrap the image in a container, then have the image and as well as a close-button inside of the container. Something like: `<div class="container"> <img> <span>X</span> </div>`. You'll want to give the image a relative positioning to be able to stack it below the span. The span should have absolute positioning, and then you can position it wherever you like using top/left/bottom/right properties.

Answer (score 54):

Usual approach with `position: relative` and `position: absolute`.

HTML:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrap {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
.img-wrap .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    z-index: 100;
    ...
}
```

Extended demo (+ JS interaction) http://jsfiddle.net/yHNEv/

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    <img src="http://wecision.com/enterprise/images/icons/closeIcon.png" style="position: absolute; top: 4px; right: 5px"/>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ugqKw/2/)

Answer (score 3):

I have coded one up for you http://jsfiddle.net/PPN7Q/

You need to wrap the image in a DIV

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="http://96pix.com/images/renee-v.jpg" />
 <a href="">Delete</a>
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS rules

```
.thumbnail {
width:50px;
height:50px;
position:relative;
}

.thumbnail img {
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}

.thumbnail a {
display:block;
width:10px;
height:10px;
position:absolute;
top:3px;
right:3px;
background:#c00;
overflow:hidden;
text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Comment: Here we can get click event for Main image and Delete ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can just set `style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;"` for `RemoveButton.ico` and `style="position:relative;"` for `div` with `img`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style=" float: right;margin-left: 289px;position: absolute;">*</div>
<img src="score.png" width="300" height="300" />
```

Please try this. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:'mainimagewidth'">
main image<img src="" />
<span style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;">ximage<img src="" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write a plugin for this

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

'use strict';

var defaults = {};

var Delete = function (element) {

    // You can access all lightgallery variables and functions like this.
    this.core = $(element).data('lightGallery');

    this.$el = $(element);
    this.core.s = $.extend({}, defaults, this.core.s)

    this.init();

    return this;
}

Delete.prototype.init = function () {
    var deleteIcon = '<span id="lg-clear" class="lg-icon deletePicture"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></span>';
    this.core.$outer.find('.lg-toolbar').append(deleteIcon);

    this.delete();

};


Delete.prototype.delete = function () {
    var that = this;
    var image_id = '';
    this.core.$outer.find('.deletePicture').on('click', function () {
    // get vars from data-* attribute
        image_id = that.core.$items.eq(that.core.index).data('id');
        table_name = that.core.$items.eq(that.core.index).data('table-name');

        /**
         * Remove Touchpoint Retailer Image
         */
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image_id', image_id);
        $.ajax(......).success(function()
        {
            var thumbcount = that.core.$outer.find('.lg-thumb-item').length;
            if(thumbcount >= 1) {
                // remove slides
            }
            else {
                that.core.destroy();
            }
        });

    });
}


/**
 * Destroy function must be defined.
 * lightgallery will automatically call your module destroy function
 * before destroying the gallery
 */
Delete.prototype.destroy = function () {

}

// Attach your module with lightgallery
$.fn.lightGallery.modules.delete = Delete;


})(jQuery, window, document);
```