# jQuery mobile- display a delete icon when upload a picture

Tags: image, jquery-mobile, imageicon

I have to display a delete icon (png file) when the user upload a picture.

I use the following code for display the picture

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $file = $('input[type=file]');
    $('a.ui-icon-camera').click(function () {
        $file.trigger("click");
    });
    $file.change(function () {
    var file = $file[0].files[0];
    $(this).fileExif(someCallback);
    displayAsImage3(file,"showPic");
});
});

function displayAsImage3(file, containerid) {
        if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
            var container = document.getElementById(containerid),
                    img = document.createElement("img"),
                    reader;
            $(img).addClass('smallImg');
            $('#'+containerid).empty();
            container.appendChild(img);
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theImg) {
                return function (evt) {
                    theImg.src = evt.target.result;
                };
            }(img));
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    <div class="hiddenfile"><input type="file" name=${pictureName} accept="image/*" /></div>
<div id="showPic" style="background-color: #E5E5E5; margin: -7% 0; margin-bottom: 1px ">
</div>
```

How can I append to the image the png icon?

Comment: add the HTML code too so we know were the pictures get appended to. any other info you can provide, as to where is the button going to go, on top of the pictures or in a header/ footer etc etc. Sticking some code in your question wont help anyone as to your question. You need to provide as much info as possible and as best you can.

Comment: The icon need to at the right-top corner of the img

Comment: You can find a demo here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272191/how-to-show-delete-button-in-top-right-corner-of-image